# objective c [__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I declared **DATA** as below

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *DATA;

My table in console DATA is :

```
(
    {
    comment = "";
    deadline = deadline;
    id = 2;
    responsible = "responsable action 1";
    status = pending;
    title = "";
}
)
```

But problem in `NSLog(@"%@",[DATA objectForKey:@"deadline"]);`

Comment: Looks like your DATA contains array of dictionaries, not just a dictionary. Check the code where you set value to this property.

Comment: Try this: NSLog(@"%@",[DATA[0] objectForKey:@"deadline"]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using this `DATA` object as a `NSDictionary` but it is a `NSArray`. You can check your log which is start from `(` which indicate it is a Array.

You can also check like this,

```
    if ([DATA isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
      //then this is dictionary
    }else{
        // other datatype
    }
```

before use as `NSLog(@"%@",[DATA objectForKey:@"deadline"])`.

If you want to access for now you can use as, but for that this DATA should be as `NSArray or NSMutableArray`.

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *DATA;`

```
[[DATA objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"deadline"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The above JSON response is an Array and not a Dictionary, () = Array and {} = Dictionary.

Ideally, you should have something like,

```
{  
   "comment":"",
   "deadline":"deadline",
   "id":2,
   "responsible":"responsable action 1",
   "status":"pending",
   "title":""
}
```

Still, you can try using an array instead of a dictionary and check if it gives you an error while parsing.